# Importing a class with Typescript

Tags: typescript, import, module, path

I'm trying to import a class called review I have from another typescript file called review.ts into my review-service.ts file however I don't know why I'm getting an error but I don't think the review.ts file I have is being imported properly into the review-service.ts file.

The image below is the file with the error which outlines the path of the file I'm trying to import from and the file structure of the app

[image: Screenshot 1]

Also in another screenshot I have it shows the "module" for the path is coming up as *. I have no idea why this is an I've tried many different paths to try get this to work.

[image: Screenshot 2]

The constents of review.ts are as follows

```
  //review.ts
  export class Review {
    _id: number;
    description: string;
    isComplete: boolean;
  }
```

Comment: you shouln't have .ts at the end of the import, just review.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import {Review} from '../app/review'
```

instead of

```
import {Review} from '../app/review.ts'
```

That's all :)